404 javascript: local server would not see Index.html
I keep having issue with localhost:8000 not being able to "see" index.html file. I am using Deno on Mac and here are my html and javascript codes:
Javascript:

import { Application } from "https://deno.land/x/oak@v12.6.1/mod.ts";

// static server serves files from the public directory
// exitSignal is used to shut down the server when the process exits (ctrl-c)
import { createExitSignal, staticServer } from "../shared/server.ts";

// create web server and set it up to serve static files from public
const app = new Application();
app.use(staticServer);

// tell the user we are about to start
console.log("\nListening on http://localhost:8000");

// start the web server
await app.listen({ port: 8000, signal: createExitSignal() });


Html:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello, Web</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, Web!</h1>
    <p>This static html page was served by hello_web.js</p>
  </body>
</html>


a screenshot of Finder folder with files deno.lock, hello_web.js, and deno.json, and folder named "public" containing index.html
I am running the server (meaning I do get signal that js is listening to server), but whenever I attempt to run related index.html file I keep receiving this error:
a 404 error screen in browser, with inspector turned on
Here is happily running server:
terminal screenshot saying "Listening on http://localhost:8000"
I am using macOS 13.2 (22D49) and Deno 1.42.1
I did restart computer, I did try duplicating the code. I tried running other files: index.html would open with no server, but server wouldn't see index.html. I tried renaming the files. I tried cleaning up cache. I tried reverting code to the moment when it was working. Everything had same result of server not seeing index.html
How can I fix it?

Can you edit the question to include a [mre]?
